# Network Analysis - Service Area Tool doesn't consider all lines?

Tags: qgis, service-area, qgis-network-analysis

using the Service Area Tool from the Network Analysis (Toolbox) gives strange results. As you can see on the screenshot the calculated blue service area (network: streets; start points: points; path type: shortest; no advanced parameters set) does contain some of the side roads some others not although they should be clearly inside the service area. How is this possibile?

[image: screenshot]

I already checked the streets layer (no gaps) and tried to run it with a multiline- and singleline-Layer (same result). Layers are in the same projected coordinate system. I'm using QGIS 3.6.3-Noosa.

Would be very happy if someone had an idea how to handle this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How have you checked that there are no gaps? Gaps might be extremely small (fraction of a mm in real world distances), but still prevent the lines to be connected. Try to set a topology tolerance value to bridge such gaps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue where lines weren't included for no obvious reason. I dissolved the network line layer before running the Service Area tool and these lines are now included.